# How do you handle scenarios involving screen lock/unlock in Appium?

Tags: appium

I am writing automation suite for an android app, I want to add a test case for handling scenarios involving screen lock/unlock, please let me know how can I do that? currently I am not locking my Device.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the below to unlock the device if it is locked. This method will return silently if the device is not locked.

```
((AndroidDriver)driver).unlockDevice();
```